# How can I code this with SQL code in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models such as `Community`, `Tagging`, and `Tag`

- Community `belongs_to :tag`
- Tagging `has_one :community` <= taggable_id will be Community's id
- Tagging `belongs_to :tag`
- Tag `has_many :taggings` # Tag has 'name' attribute

In this situation, if I had params[:tag], how can I write SQL code to fetch all the communities with tagged by params[:tag]?

Comment: Are you sure a Community is not belonging to Tagging?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I use the gem called "acts_as_taggable_on_steroid", it's polymorphic so it has taggable_type and taggable_id instead of community_id

Comment: this gem is pretty old (last date of modification on Github: 2 years ago: https://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids). You should use this one before you get too deep in your implementation: https://github.com/ivoreis/acts_as_taggable

Comment: @Mr.Yoshiji sorry about that thats what I'm using now

Comment: @MrYoshiji The reason why I'm trying to do this with SQL code is, it won't return the community who absolutely has the particular tag.  It's really weird. This never happened in development mode :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see the exact sql generated when you try

```
 Community.find_tagged_with(params[:tag])
```

But you should also be able to create the query yourself using the following

```
 # Rails 3
 Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where(tags: { name: params[:tag] })

 # Rails 2
 Community.all(joins: { taggings: :tag }, conditions: { tags: { name: params[:tag] } })
```

Comment: Thanks but it's funny that it returns 2 same communities records if the community had tags "apple" and "Apple". one in lower case and another in upper case. Can you restrict this?

Comment: I means. I see 2 records of communities in result. But there are the same community.